# Proving inequality with Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

I have the following problem:

Show that if $144\leq a\leq b\leq 169$ is true, then

$\frac{a-b}{64}\leq \sin\sqrt{a}-\sin\sqrt{b}\leq\frac{a-b}{36}$.

That $3<\pi<\frac{22}{7}$ can be used.

I figure this problem should be solved using the Mean Value Theorem and that you should divide by $a-b$.

$\frac{a-b}{64}\leq \sin\sqrt{a}-\sin\sqrt{b}\leq\frac{a-b}{36}$ $\Leftrightarrow$
$\frac{1}{64}\leq \frac{\sin\sqrt{a}-\sin\sqrt{b}}{a-b}\leq\frac{1}{36}$

MVT gives that there is some $c$ $\epsilon$ $[b,a]$ where
$\frac{1}{64}\leq \frac{\sin\sqrt{a}-\sin\sqrt{b}}{a-b}=f'(c)\leq\frac{1}{36}$ where $f(x)=\sin\sqrt{x}$ so that $f'(c)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}} \cos\sqrt{c}$

which gives $\frac{1}{64}\leq \frac{\cos\sqrt{c}}{2\sqrt{c}} \leq\frac{1}{36}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{1}{32}\leq \frac{\cos\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{c}} \leq\frac{1}{18}$.

Not sure where to go from here, how to get from here to the initial inequality. Also not sure how the pi inequality above factors into the solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(4 - \frac{1}{3}\right) \pi < \frac{7 \cdot 12}{22} \pi < 12 \le \sqrt{\xi} \le 13 < \frac{13}{3} \pi = \left(4 + \frac{1}{3}\right) \pi$$

You can check that $\cos(\pi x)$ is $\ge 1/2$ for $4 - \frac{1}{3} \le x \le 4 + \frac{1}{3}$.

Combining this fact with
$\frac{1}{13} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}} \le \frac{1}{12}$
yields

$$\frac{1}{2 \cdot 13} \le \frac{\cos \sqrt{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}} \le \frac{1}{2 \cdot 12}$$

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, the checking is done by the cosine addition and subtraction formulas? Also, how would one arrive at the inequality at the top row?

Comment: @JohnSchwarzMath99 The top row comes from combining $\xi \in [a,b]$ and $144 \le a < b \le 169$ and $3 < \pi < \frac{22}{7}$. The function $\cos(\pi x)$ on $[4-1/3, 4+1/3]$ is the same as on $[-1/3, 1/3]$, and we know $\cos(\pm\pi/3) = 1/2$.

Comment: Is there anything left to show after getting to $\frac{1}{2\cdot13} \leq \frac{\cos\sqrt{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}} \leq \frac{1}{2\cdot12}$? Not sure how to make it equivalent with $\frac{1}{52} \leq \frac{\cos\sqrt{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}} \leq \frac{1}{24}$

Comment: @JohnSchwarzMath99 Double check the end of your question, you want bounds of $\frac{1}{26}$ and $\frac{1}{12}$, and the approach in my answer achieves tighter than that.